# Existence of finite dimensional topological subspaces

Tags: general-topology, dimension-theory-analysis

Are there any conditions known for infinite dimensional topological spaces to have finite dimensional subspaces? (Non-trivial: no points nor the empty set.) With dimension being the Lebesgue dimension or some other topological definition of dimension.

Comment: Do you also want to exclude countable subsets? See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2572632/closed-subset-of-perfect-complete-metric-space-is-homeomorphic-to-cantor-set

Comment: It's going to be tricky to find general conditions like that: there are (totally disconnected) infinite-dimensional separable metric spaces $X$ (so all standard dim-functions coincide) such that the only finite-dimensional subspaces of $X$ have dimension $0$.

Comment: Of course path-connectedness is a rather trivial such condition.